# how to treat with datatable in mysql and c# form application?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, datatable

I have mysql database and there is a table with a name Cars.
I bring Cars table from mysql by using MySqlDataAdapter then fill a datatable.
I use only that datatable to feed the controls that represent a car information on the form and by using a loop I take the next row in `this.carsDT`. then I feed datagridview source from this data table

```
MySqlDataAdapter carsMSDA = new MySqlDataAdapter(mysql, conn);
carsMSDA.Fill(this.carsDT);
dataGridViewCars.DataSource = this.carsDT;
```

The problem is after updatting a row in anothe place of the code, I call again the lines above to make something like refresh or renew `this.carsDT`. But I find that rows in `this.carsDT` and `dataGridViewCars` are doubled for e.g.
if there was 3 rows they will become 6 rows, 3 are the old from previouse state bfore updating a row, and 3 other one of them the updated row.
So I used new datatable like this:

```
MySqlDataAdapter carsMSDA = new MySqlDataAdapter(mysql, conn);
DataTable carsDT = new DataTable();
carsMSDA.Fill(carsDT);
this.carsDT = carsDT;
//carsMSDA.Fill(this.carsDT);
dataGridViewCars.DataSource = this.carsDT;
```

I want to notice that after close the form and run again I find it normal and uptaded as it should be.
Is this good idea?

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it will be for users to help you.

Comment: by the look of your problem it seems like you arent using the bind correctly if you bind all the cars from db on each post back and dont check IsPostback you will multiple the rows in the gridview ( because of the view state, you can also use the Clear function of the gridview to rebind the cars, depends on your needs, if im being unclear please ask me to clarify